# How to prevent redirection while clicking heading in structural navigation?

Tags: 2013, navigation

I have modified the navigation items by adding heading and link using Structural Navigation editing and sorting.

[image]

While adding the heading(MY WORKSPACE), i have given the URL as empty but while clicking the heading redirection to another link takes place.

[image]

How to Prevent this?

Comment: This is working as expected, on heading by keeping it empty it does not form hyperlink and it is not clickable. Tried in 2010 and 2013. which version you are using, and where it is redirecting ?

Comment: I am using 2013 and it redirects to same site collection(reloading takes place). I have given URL empty but it shows site collection URL. I have tried by deleting another time and saved it but same site collection URL remains.

Comment: it is strange...are you using any custom css or js file ? because in 2013 is not not clickable...

Comment: Can you please check if there is space in your field URL ?

Comment: Yeah!! I am using custom master page and that includes custom CSS and Scripts

Comment: No. There is no space in field the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By providing the URL as empty it takes the welcome page URL by default.It is possible to provide URL as '/javascript:return true;' but still the page will reload.Finally I found the solution by removing the attribute 'href' of heading using jquery.

Code:

```
     var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul[id^=zz][id$=_RootAspMenu] > li > a');
     for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       $(elements[i]).removeAttr('href');
     }
```